# How to append after or other solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table border="2">
    <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" id="new" >add new</td></tr>
</table>

$('#new').click(function(){
   $('#new').append("<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>");
})
```

Now if i click "add new" then this make:

```
one | two
one | two
add new
one  two
```

How can i make:

```
one | two
one | two
one | two
add new
```

**LIVE:** http://jsfiddle.net/tg5qD/

Comment: `$('#new').parent().before("...")`

Comment: @Esailija If you will paste this as an answer I will vote for you? Go on bruv B-)

Comment: @Esailija please add new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/eDNH5/2/

**Another Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/eDNH5/5/

API: http://api.jquery.com/before/

**Updated another way**

```
$('#new').click(function(){
    $('table tr:last').before('<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>');
})​
```

**code**

```
$('#new').click(function(){
   $('#new').parent().before("<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>");
})​
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#new').click(function(){
   $('#new').parent('tr').before("<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>");
})​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nawazhi/tg5qD/7/)

Answer (score 1):

You can either modify your JavaScript code in the following way:

```
$('#new').click(function(){
   $('#new').parent().before("<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>");
})
```

Or modify your HTML as well, to use that script.

```
<table border="2">
    <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>
    <tr id="new"><td colspan="2" >add new</td></tr>
</table>
<script>
  $('#new').click(function(){
    $('#new').before("<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>");
  });
</script>
```

The second solution appends the click handler to the row instead of the cell. That way you can easily use `before` ([jQuery docu](http://api.jquery.com/before/)).

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/tg5qD/5/

```
$('#new').on('click', function(){
   $('#new').parent().before("<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>");
})​
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) insted of [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/tg5qD/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#new').click(function(){
   $('#new').parent('tr').before("<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>");
})
```

**demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/tg5qD/4/

Answer (score 1):

I would actually reference the add new button using `$(this)` within the click event. Saves you finding the element in the DOM again.

```
$('#new').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().before("<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>");
})
```

Better still if you use the `.on` event object you have the flexibility to turn off this click event at a later point if you wish.

```
$('#new').on({
   "click.addNew": function(){
       $(this).parent().before("<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>");
   }
})
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tg5qD/11/

Answer (score 1):

You can use following way.. First need to find parent `tr` of the id 'new'. then we can append our new element to before parent element.

```
$('#new').click(function(){
   $(this).parent('tr').before("<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>");
})​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#new').click(function(){
   $("<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>").insertBefore($(this).parent());
});
```

Read about [.insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/7GZAa/)**